# Using the pst-poker package to display a hand of 13 cards

Tags: pstricks, cards

I want to show a hand containing 13 cards, using the pst-poker package. I wish the cards would sit on top of the other and only the corner peek. Something like these two options (but with 13 cards):

[image]

[image]

I didn't find how to do this in *[pst-poker](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-poker/doc/pst-poker-doc.pdf)*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not exactly circular, because of the way `\rotatebox` works, but it can be tweaked by playing with the angles and the `110pt` offset.

Also, `pst-poker` takes a lonnng time to typeset.  Use XeLaeX.

While these MWEs are done with the default shadowing, hat tip to Paul Gaborit for noting that one may employ the `crdshadow=none` option to suppress them.

Here with `110pt` offset and 7 degree delta:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-poker, rotating, stackengine}
\newcommand\inhand[3][110pt]{\rotatebox[origin=b]{#2}{\raisebox{#1}{#3}}}
\begin{document} 
\setstackgap{L}{0pt} 
\Longunderstack{%
\inhand{42}{\crdAs}
\inhand{35}{\crdtenh}
\inhand{28}{\crdsevd}
\inhand{21}{\crdsevc}
\inhand{14}{\crdQd}
\inhand{7}{\crdtenh}
\inhand{0}{\crdsevc}
\inhand{-7}{\crdQd}
\inhand{-14}{\crdAs}
\inhand{-21}{\crdsevc}
\inhand{-28}{\crdQd}
\inhand{-35}{\crdtenh}
\inhand{-42}{\crdsevc}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a variation with a `150pt` offset, and 5 degree delta:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-poker, rotating, stackengine}
\newcommand\inhand[3][150pt]{\rotatebox[origin=b]{#2}{\raisebox{#1}{#3}}}
\begin{document} 
\setstackgap{L}{0pt} 
\Longunderstack{%
\inhand{30}{\crdAs}
\inhand{25}{\crdtenh}
\inhand{20}{\crdsevd}
\inhand{15}{\crdsevc}
\inhand{10}{\crdQd}
\inhand{5}{\crdtenh}
\inhand{0}{\crdsevc}
\inhand{-5}{\crdQd}
\inhand{-10}{\crdAs}
\inhand{-15}{\crdsevc}
\inhand{-20}{\crdQd}
\inhand{-25}{\crdtenh}
\inhand{-30}{\crdsevc}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, `250pt` offset and 4 degree delta:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-poker, rotating, stackengine}
\newcommand\inhand[3][250pt]{\rotatebox[origin=b]{#2}{\raisebox{#1}{#3}}}
\begin{document} 
\setstackgap{L}{0pt} 
\Longunderstack{%
\inhand{24}{\crdAs}
\inhand{20}{\crdtenh}
\inhand{16}{\crdsevd}
\inhand{12}{\crdsevc}
\inhand{8}{\crdQd}
\inhand{4}{\crdtenh}
\inhand{0}{\crdsevc}
\inhand{-4}{\crdQd}
\inhand{-8}{\crdAs}
\inhand{-12}{\crdsevc}
\inhand{-16}{\crdQd}
\inhand{-20}{\crdtenh}
\inhand{-24}{\crdsevc}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is an inline version

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-poker, rotating, stackengine}
\newcommand\inline[1]{#1\kern-35pt\ignorespaces}
\begin{document} 
\inline{\crdAs}
\inline{\crdtenh}
\inline{\crdsevd}
\inline{\crdsevc}
\inline{\crdQd}
\inline{\crdtenh}
\inline{\crdsevc}
\inline{\crdQd}
\inline{\crdAs}
\inline{\crdsevc}
\inline{\crdQd}
\inline{\crdtenh}
\inline{\crdsevc}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that great! Can I present it in a straight line?

Comment: @Cohensius Kust negative kern after each card.  See update.

Comment: Here, the shadows are not pretty. You can use the `crdshadow=none` option...